# Why cannot i attach to the focus event but can to the blur event of a textbox?

Tags: jquery, focus

simple code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var txtAtm = jQuery("#txtAtm");
    txtAtm.on("focus", function () {
    alert("Focus!");
});

//txtAtm.blur(function () {
//    alert("Blur!");
//});

  txtAtm.on("blur", function () {
    alert("Blur!");
  });

});
```

The blur code works fine, the focus code does not!!  ANY IDEAS??

If i change the event to focusin it works but captures the Tab key also moving the contents of the box!!

The form is a webform with the following markup, i was looking to replace the inline markup (which works!!) with jQuery and was just looking to confirm i can capture the events!! (failed at the first hurdle!!):

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAtm" runat="server" CssClass="withUnit"
            AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="prv">not set</asp:TextBox>
```

The rendered HTML is which looks like standard autopost code for a webform control:

```
<input name="ctl00$leftContent$ctl07$txtAtm" type="text" value="not set"
  onchange="javascript:setTimeout('WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$leftContent$ctl07$txtAtm&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;prv&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))', 0)" 
  onkeypress="if (WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) == false) return false;" 
  id="txtAtm" class="withUnit">
```

Comment: neither of them should work as you need to use the clientId in the jQuery - eg `$('#<%= txtAtm.ClientId %>')`

Comment: @Pete: The *rendered* id shown is apparently already correct for the code: `id="txtAtm"`

Comment: ah yeah sorry, I read the name as the id - usually that's how the id is rendered as well with asp controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the super-quick answers, it looks like it was a timing issue!!  Looks like "ready" is not "ready!"  The following code works:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
///<summary>
/// Replaces the inline markup
///</summary>

var txtAtm = jQuery("#txtAtm");

setTimeout(function () {
    txtAtm.on("focus", function () {
        txtAtm.select();
        //alert("Focus!");
    })
}, 1000);


txtAtm.on("blur", function () {
    //alert("Blur!");
    initBox(this.id, 'not set');
});

txtAtm.on("click", function () {
    txtAtm.select();
});
```

});

Annoyingly, the script ref is also at the end of the page so you would expect minimum problems with timing!

Answer (score 1):

onkeypress you're using `return false` which is causing your code being not work.

If you remove that, it starts working as you hope.

Comment: As that code is injected by ASP, best you suggest how he remove that.

Comment: Yes, that thought had also crossed my mind - another reason why MVC is beckoning me!